# Why would a broccoli plant have grey patches on only a single leaf?

Tags: vegetables, diseases, winter-gardening, broccoli

I'm making a temporary garden for a client at home to move to the landscaping location. He requested his garden contain broccoli which is the plant I'm worried about currently. It seems to have grey patches on a single leaf at the moment.

I'm living in Australia and we are currently going through winter, minimum 2° celcius (35° fahrenheit) nights and 8° celcius (46° fahrenheit) days.

Here is the broccoli leaf:

[image: broccoli leaf with grey patches]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That leaf is the oldest leaf and is in the process of dying.  Totally normal.  Cut it off so that plant can concentrate its energy making its flower!

Comment: I usually wait a bit longer before removing it to give the plant time to retract whatever it wants to recycle, but otherwise I totally agree.

Comment: I am brutal.  I don't worry about weeds at all but as I am putzing with plants I am ripping dead, dying leaves off the plants and throwing them into my center aisle.  This also helps with ventilation.  Have you watched any recent documentaries on the intelligence of plants?  I should send you one...plants probably like you better than me!!!  Grinning widely!

Comment: @stormy what a beautiful message to re-read, if you have any documentaries please send them through! I've been meaning to listen to the secret life of trees.